# List all issues for a repo using github_api gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, github-api

I'm using the github_api gem for rails and I'm trying to list all of the issues attached to a specific repo within an organisation I am a member of.

I'm using

```
    @github = Github.new :oauth_token => 'token',
                     :org => 'org-name',
                     :user => 'org-name',
                     :repo => 'repo-name'

@issues = @github.issues.list state: 'open'
```

which returns just the issues I am assigned to - changing the state to 'closed' returns nothing - but prodding the endpoint myself using curl returns all the issues I am looking for.

Does anyone know how to list all of the issues associated with a specific repo - and not just the ones assigned to yourself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After wrestling with the documentation for this gem - I found you can tap in to the github search api - allowing you to search issues for a repo - and provide flags to filter the results.

```
@github = Github.new :oauth_token => 'token',
                 :org => 'org-name',
                 :user => 'org-name',
                 :repo => 'repo-name'

@github.search.issues 'repo:user/repo type:pr state:closed updated:>=2015-10-15'
```

Looking at the Github api documentation shows what you can filter the results by. I hope this helps anyone else who is having issues with this gem.